# Loop MySQL to insert data in table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to insert data in a database for assign an id to each number

```
table numbers

id | number

1  | 2560
2  | 2561
```

And this go on for 100 numbers. I found this for PL/SQL

```
BEGIN
   FOR v_LoopCounter IN 2560..2660 LOOP
   INSERT INTO numbers (number)
   VALUES (v_LoopCounter);
END LOOP;
END;
```

Also tried like

```
BEGIN
   FOR v_LoopCounter IN 2560.2660 LOOP;
   INSERT INTO numbers (number);
   VALUES (v_LoopCounter);
END LOOP;
END;
```

How can I do this in SQL using phpMyAdmin, for that's what I can use? I tried it but I get this error:

> There seems to be an error in your SQL query. The MySQL server error output below, if there is any, may also help you in diagnosing the problem

I also have tried now

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE
BEGIN
       FOR v_LoopCounter IN 2560..2660 LOOP
       INSERT INTO numbers (number)
       VALUES (v_LoopCounter);
    END LOOP;
    END;
```

Comment: You can do this on any SQL screen... cut and paste.

Comment: There is a Syntax Error i cant Fix. because i dont see it... Maybe thats why i thought , this code wont run on sql phmyadmin

Comment: `SELECT * FROM WHERE 1BEGIN ...` You left the 1 in the WHERE statement, and need to reference the aliased table name.  Change it to `SELECT * FROM yourAliasTableName WHERE BEGIN`

Comment: I got ERROR: Invalid Identifer @ 31
STR: 2560..

Answer (score 0):

Try this
SELECT a database first else you will get the no database selected error

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS myFunction;
delimiter $$

CREATE PROCEDURE myFunction()
     BEGIN
             DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
             DECLARE j INT DEFAULT 0;
             DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;
             CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test
                 (id int, numbers int);

         WHILE (i<=100) DO
                SET j=i+2560;
                INSERT INTO test VALUES(i,j);
                SET i=i+1;
         END WHILE;

         select * from test;

         drop table test;

 END$$
```

After that call the procedure

```
delimiter ;

call myFunction();
```

Comment: using phpmyadmin. you cannot do this inline

Answer (score 0):

--- You can not use FOR loop in PHPMyAdmin ---

Use this way :-

1. Print all your queries and copy it.
2. Paste it in sql tab and press GO.
3. Done.

   Example :-

   ```
    str = "";
    for (let i = 8; i < 77; i++) {
        str = str + "HERE IS YOU QUERY YOU WANT... Like DELETE FROM tabel_name WHERE column_id=+i+;\n"
    }
    console.log(str);
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Try :

```
DELIMITER //
BEGIN
   FOR v_LoopCounter IN 2560..2660 LOOP
   INSERT INTO numbers (number)
   VALUES (v_LoopCounter);
END LOOP;
END
//
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 'FOR v_LoopCounter IN 2560..2660 LOOP INSERT INTO numbers (number) VALUES (v' at line 2

Comment: +1 DOESNT WORK IN PHPMYADMIN for the right syntax to use near 'FOR v_LoopCounter IN 2560..2660 LOOP select 1; END LOOP; END' at line 2