# mysql: trigger to create n number of rows after insert in another row

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am using mysql and phpmyadmin and I have two tables in mysql database:

> job (ID int, milestones int, description VARCHAR(50))
>   which will store a job and its number of milestones and the description of that job

the second table is:

> milestones (ID int, jobID - reference the job ID as a foreign key , description VARCHAR(50) )

what I want is to create a trigger of every insertion of a job, so if I inserted a job with 2 milestones, I want 2 rows created in the milestones table.

for example:

```
INSERT INTO `job`(`ID`, `name`, `mileStones`)
VALUES (1,'its a good project',2);
```

I want to automatically create 2 rows in the milestones table as follow:

1,1,'milestone'

2,1,'milestone'

what I did is I followed some questions like:
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546435/loop-mysql-to-insert-data-in-table-using-phpmyadmin) and I came up with this code

```
 DELIMITER //
 CREATE TRIGGER job_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON job
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
    WHILE (i<=NEW.milestones) DO
            INSERT INTO milestones(ID, jobID, description) VALUES   ( i      ,NEW.ID,'milestone')
    END WHILE;
 END; //
 DELIMITER ;
```

when I insert a row into job, I get the following error:

> #1442 - Can't update table 'job' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

can you explain to me what is wrong with this approach ?

Comment: Do you have a trigger for your `milestones`-table that tries to access the `job` table? That will not work.

Comment: First of all, you have an infinite loop because you do not increase the value of the `i` variable.

Comment: @Solarflare yes, when a milestones is inserted , I increment the number of milestones in job table by a trigger. any work around ?

Comment: @Shadow I added SET i = i +1;

Comment: Your business logic seems flawed, it would go around in circles. You determine the number of milestones based on a field's value in the jobs table, and then in return the number of milestones impact the same field's value. You should not store the number of milestones in the jobs table.

Comment: @Shadow what I can think of is that, they are inter-related yes. but all updates the field in different situation or different trigger 

ON INSERT on milestones ----> add one to the milestones field in jobs,,

ON delete on milestones ----> minus one from the milestones field in jobs,,

ON insert on job ------>  insert milestones equal to the number of milestones! 

do you suggest making another table just to store the number of milestones, is there a better approach ?

Comment: @SabirMoglad You don't need to store the number of milestones anywhere. That information already exists: You can calculate it by counting the number of rows in your table. If you store that number, you would duplicate that information, which is not a good idea. The problem of keeping your data in sync, which you are having right now, is an example of why. To automatically add them, you could create a procedure that inserts a row to the `job` table and a given number of new rows to the `milestones` table, or you just add the milestones when you add the job in your (php?) code.

Comment: @Solarflare thanks. I was mainly going to use php to insure data integrity, but I was informed to use triggers whenever its possible. but now I will go for php